# My small FolderBrowserDialog implementation does not work

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog, folderbrowserdialog

I know there are a lot of FolderBrowserDialog implementations for WPF available.
But my idea was writing a facade for OpenFileDialog and set the FOS_PICKFOLDERS flag, instead of writing a complete new implementation.

But it does not work.

```
public sealed class FolderDialog 
{
    private OpenFileDialog dlg;

    public FolderDialog()
    {
        this.dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        SetOption(0x00000020, true);    // FOS_PICKFOLDERS  
        bool b = GetOption(0x00000020);
    }

    private bool GetOption(int option)
    {
        return (bool)typeof(FileDialog).InvokeMember("GetOption", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, this.dlg, new object[] { option });
    }

    private void SetOption(int option, bool value)
    {
        typeof(FileDialog).InvokeMember("SetOption", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, this.dlg, new object[] { option, value });
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return this.dlg.Title; }
        set { this.dlg.Title = value; }
    }

    public string FileName 
    {
        get { return this.dlg.FileName; }
    }

    public bool? ShowDialog()
    {
        return this.dlg.ShowDialog();
    }

    public bool? ShowDialog(Window owner)
    {
        return this.dlg.ShowDialog(owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to identify any specific symptoms of it not working?

Comment: It shows the default OpenFileDialog and ignores the FOS_PICKFOLDERS flag.

Comment: Are you meaning to call [`IFileDialog.SetOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with that flag? I think what you're actually calling is `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.SetOption()`, which sets OFN_* flags (Ctrl+F for "SetOption" [in this source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/Microsoft/Win32/OpenFileDialog@cs/1/OpenFileDialog@cs#631)).

Comment: 0x00000020 is OFN_ENABLEHOOK: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ofn_enablehook